# How to know which button of button array is clicked

Tags: c#, arrays, button

I have array of buttons, which length is variable that User types in. So I made one eventHandler for all buttons. But I have a problem, I need to know which Button is clicked so I can in eventHandler do something that I want. It's more complicated in my code, but I have summarized it. Actually, I just need index of that button that has been clicked.

```
    public Button[] btn;

    public void creatingButtons()
    {
        btn = new Button[x];
        for(int i=0; i<btn.Length; i++){
            Controls.Add(btn[i]);
            btn[i].Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        }
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender , EventArgs e)
    {
        int index;
        btn[index].Text = "This is clicked button";
    }
```

Comment: that is *precisely* what the `sender` parameter passed to the event handler is for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the documentation (found as ~first result by googling "c# button click")

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8

```
public Button[] btns;

public void createButtons(int count) {
  btns = new Button[count];
  for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    btns[i] = new Button()
    Controls.Add(btns[i]);
    btns[i].Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
  }
}

private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
  int index = Array.IndexOf(btns, clickedButton);

  clickedButton.Text = "...button clicked...";

}
```

Note that you can cast the sender as a `Button`, and presumably use `Array.IndexOf` to find the index.

Comment: `btns.Length` is not defined yet, when you create `btns`. Also, this is an array containing nulls after creation and you must create the buttons `btns[i] = new Button();`

Answer (score 2):

the Sender is the object what is being clicked so you can use:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender , EventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedBut = sender as Button;
    clickedBut.Text = "This is clicked button";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have pointed out, you can use `sender`.

But a better solution would be to add a different click handler for the button. If the click handler needs to do different things for each button, or group of buttons then it's technically a different handler. During the creation of the button, you know the purpose of the button, you have the instance of the button, so make the decision then and add an appropriate handler for it.

This way your code is following OOP principles, has good separation of concerns rather than a bunch of adhoc if-statements patched together as an afterthought.

Comment: Thanks for answer! But how can I add  x  eventHandlers? I don't know how many buttons will my array have, becouse the Length of the my array depends of User input.

Comment: @dennistalovic **1)** What do you mean it depends on user input? **2)** And what exactly do you need to do different based on button?

Comment: Actualy I don't need to get what I asked, I just needed Index. My app is too much complicated to explain.
Basicaly, I am making some shoping app, so firstly user needs to add articles so they can exists with textboxes that I made. Then he can buy, sell those articles. He just need to click on button which article he wants to sell. So I dont know how many articles will he add, which means I don't know what is length of my array. So I can't made private void for every Button, becouse I don't know how many Buttons will there be. I am amateur, 17yo, 1 year learning programming.